# ListContourPlot and ListPlot3D return empty (white) plots when scaled

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, ticks

using Mathematica 11.1.1.0. I could not find this topic before. Look at these simple data plots:

```
data1:={{-0.5 * 10^6, -150, 0.599102}, {-0.5 * 10^6, 150, 
   0.599102}, {0.5 * 10^6, -150, 0.599102}, {0.5 * 10^6, 150, 0.599102}};
```

Now I multiply the x-values by 10 (scaling):

```
data2:={{-0.5 *10^7, -150, 0.599102}, {-0.5 * 10^7, 150, 
   0.599102}, {0.5 * 10^7, -150, 0.599102}, {0.5 * 10^7, 150, 0.599102}};
```

The commands

```
ListPlot3D[data1, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All]
ListContourPlot[data1, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All]
```

do plot just fine their trivial result. But if I scale the first coordinate by the factor 10, i.e.:

```
ListPlot3D[data2, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All]
ListContourPlot[data2, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All]
```

they return empty plots instead of the same plots with changed axis labels. In fact it seems that this is due to the axis labels now displayed in scientific number format (a*10^b), although `Ticks-> none` does not help.

Comment: This works fine in 12.1.1 so I'm guessing it's a bug in your version.

Comment: @flinty - the problem shows up with v12.1.1 on my Mac.